# How to change color of text if it is in array php

Tags: php, regex

I am using this code to change the color of search keyword. But due to searching multiple words from query I create `$keyword` as array. So now how can I use this?

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/\p{L}*?".preg_quote($keyword)."\p{L}*/ui", "<span class='changecoolor'>$0</span>", $row['ti_name']); ?>
```

Comment: Simple way Iterate on you array. Other solution build a regex with all your words

Comment: how can i build a regex?

Comment: if i search one word it is changing the color but if i search more than one word its not changing the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match multiple words in a regexp, separate them with `|` and put them into a group.

```
$keyword_regexp = '(?:' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keyword)) . ')';
echo preg_replace("/\p{L}*?$keyword_regexp\p{L}*/ui", "<span class='changecoolor'>$0</span>", $row['ti_name']);
```

Comment: Thank You Sir :) :) It Works